# How to data model endorsement for a service provided by a person, Graph Data modeling

Tags: graph, neo4j, model, data-modeling, graph-databases

Hi I am new to graph database modeling and have some doubts about expressing an endorsment for a service provided by a Person. The use case is the following. PersonA gives Endorsement to a Service provided by PersonB.

The key point is that If I am recipient of the endorsment, I would like to know who has endorsed me. I have come up with several scenarios on how I could potentialy do that, but because of my lack of experience I have doubts on what would be the best aproach.

**Scenario 1.**

Endorsment is expressed direcly as a relationship and the service falls as a property under the endorsment So it will look like:

```
PersonA-------ENDORSE{service}--->PersonB
```

**Scenario 2**

I model an entity named Service. The problem is that when I do the relationship "ENDORSE" to service I would loose information on who am I endorsing. So I would have to keep a property in the relationship on who am I endorsing. Then the PersonB would AQUIRE endorsment for the SERVICE but he would not know who has actualy givern the endorsment. So..... it will look like this:

```
PERSONA----ENDORSE{personB}--->Service------ENDORSMENT{personA}--->PERSONB
```

Does this make sense ?

**Scenario 3:**

I normalize the second relationship "ENDORSMENT" and exclude the personA as a property , but than I need to query all Person to find out who have they endorsed.

How would you model this kind of relationship ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two important principles for validating a data model for a graph database:

- if an entity or fact can be used more than once, then it should be stored
  as the node
- if the relationship of two nodes requires to store node
  identifiers, then this relationship must be transformed into a node

So [`@Raj`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6077914/raj) pointed the right way, in which case the model might look like this:

[image]

I recommend you read this:

- https://neo4j.com/graph-databases-book/
- http://patterns.dataincubator.org/book/

Comment: I need one clarification if that would be alright. I don't understand why the direction of the relationship is from the Endorsment to the Endorsment Sender and not the opposite. Can you say something on this? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov It does not matter. As you wish. It is more convenient for me, because I interpret this `endorsement`-nodes in this case as an edges of a hypergraph.

Comment: hei I was wondering what tool do you use to drag and drop and translate to cypher?

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov Hi. I do not understand - what tool are you asking for?

Comment: I am currently using arrows to drag and drop and script generation. But it looks to me as too simplified. I was wondering if there is something more sophisticated man can use.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov Understand. We use an in-house tool for this purpose. Unfortunately, there are no plans for open-source or other plans.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach looks good, you don't have to add these properties on relationships.

It's possible to get person A who endorsed person B for service S.
The only issue with this is there will be multiple nodes for any service S.  If that's not acceptable.

You can replace the Service node in the second approach with Endorse node E and connect this E to service node S. 
So there will be four types of nodes.

**EDIT:**

Adding an image for clarification.
Rename REL1 and REL2 as you wish.
[@Stdob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4989460/stdob) suggested some good names for these relationships.
[image]